# Вывод данных в консоль python

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

У меня есть код с проверками на статус страницы

```
from ATPages import SearchHelper 
import requests
print("dsdsdsdsd")
#Проверка главной страницы расширения
def test_main(browser):
    main_page = SearchHelper(browser)
    main_page.go_to_site()
    response = requests.head(browser.current_url)
    assert response.status_code == 200

#Открываем коллекцию горячей подборки
def test_collection1(browser):
    main_page = SearchHelper(browser)
    #window_before = browser.window_handles[0]   #Запоминаем предыдущую страницу
    main_page.click_button_collection1()
    #window_after = browser.window_handles[1]     #Запоминаем новую страницу
    #browser.switch_to.window(window_after)       #Перемещаемся на новую страницу
    response = requests.head(browser.current_url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    browser.back()
print("asdasdasd23e24234")
#Бестселлеры
def test_collection2(browser):
    main_page = SearchHelper(browser)
    main_page.click_button_collection2()
    response = requests.head(browser.current_url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    browser.back()

#Покупатели рекомендуют
def test_collection3(browser):
    main_page = SearchHelper(browser)
    main_page.click_button_collection3()
    response = requests.head(browser.current_url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    print("response")
    browser.back()
```

Первые принты для проверки выводит ли код вообще что-то, в последнем то, что я хочу видеть - ответ от сервера, но у меня не выводится ни один принт, подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

Вот что выводится в консоли

```
C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Test AT>pytest test.py
==================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
sensitiveurl: .*
rootdir: C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Test AT
plugins: base-url-1.4.2, html-3.1.1, metadata-2.0.1, selenium-3.0.0, variables-1.9.0
collected 4 items

test.py
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50346/devtools/browser/4a0dfb7d-a291-4398-8426-2801e080e630
....                                                                                                                                            [100%]

===================================================================== 4 passed in 15.65s ===================================================================== 

C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Test AT>
```

P.S. Еще буду рад подсказке - как зайти в консоль и проверять переменные без print, знаю, что такой функционал есть, но никак не могу вспомнить

Comment: Если тест прошел, значит ни один assert не выдал ложное условие (и не упал с ошибкой AssertionError). Поэтому print-ы вам не нужны, достаточно видеть что тесты прошли.

Comment: print-ы между функциям вообще не имеют смысла, т.к. они выполнятся сразу при импорте модуля, а потом уже pytest начнет вызывать функции.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, с print понял, а как мне посмотреть что содержит переменная response?

Comment: Ну посмотреть можно и через `print(response)` с учетом ответа ниже. А вообще в тестах имеет смысл проверять значение через assert, а не глазами вычитываться в вывод. Если нужно содержимое ответа проверить, то нужно `requests.get` вместо `requests.head` использовать, и проверять что что-то есть в тексте ответа сервера, например: `assert "Какой-то текст" in response.text`

Comment: @insolor Да, добавил принт и увидел, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб видеть вывод теста в консоль добавьте опцию `-rP` к запуску команды:

```
pytest -rP test.py
```

Не по теме вопроса:

```
browser.back()
```

не выполнится и вероятно, следующие тесты не пройду, если `assert` будет ложным и бросит исключение или какое-то другое исключение будет брошено.

Нужно делать так:

```
def test_collection2(browser):
    main_page = SearchHelper(browser)
    main_page.click_button_collection2()
    try:
        response = requests.head(browser.current_url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
    finally:
        browser.back()
```

Или если в каждом тесте такое нужно делать, то можно это перенести в fixture и тогда явно в тесте это делать не нужно:

```
@pytest.fixture
def browser(browser):
    try:
        yield browser
    finally:
        browser.back()


def test_collection2(browser):
    ...
    assert response.status_code == 200
    # browser.back() делать не нужно, об этом позаботиться наша fixture
```

Comment: Прописал, вывод тот же

C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Test AT>pytest -s test.py
==================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
sensitiveurl: .*
rootdir: C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\Test AT
plugins: base-url-1.4.2, html-3.1.1, metadata-2.0.1, selenium-3.0.0, variables-1.9.0
collected 4 items

test.py
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49298/devtools/browser/8d7c8604-272f-4d05-bdb5-b684856bf0b1
....

Comment: Да действительно, `-s` показывает вывод только, когда тест не прошел. Подправил ответ.

Comment: Добавил в код print и увидел ответ, большое спасибо!

Comment: Привет! Добавляю фикстуру и все тесты валятся, думаю это из-за того, что первый тест проверяет главную страницу и ему не нужно возвращаться назад, после этого открывается после белая страница и дальнейшие тесты падают, есть какой-то способ запускать эту фикстуру только на нужных тестах?

Comment: нужно отдельный вопрос задать. в комментариях не ответить подробно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1420795/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc